# What version of Mono is included by default?

Tags: mono

What version of mono ships by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mono-complete` package in Ubuntu Trusty is version 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/mono-complete

All the packages has the same version number.

Answer (score 4):

To determine the version number, simply type in: `mono -V`

On Debian 6.08 (squeeze) it is: `version 2.6.7`